# Sort a csv in shell and keep only the top values

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, csv

I have a csv looking like this:

```
user, score
bob, 10
alice, 12
peter, 20
bruce, 32
...
```

The file is quite big and I'd like to get the top 50 users with the highest score.

How can I do this with a simple shell command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to say:

```
sort -t',' -k2 -nr file
```

For your given input it returns:

```
bruce, 32
peter, 20
alice, 12
bob, 10
user, score
```

This uses `sort` with these parameters:

- `-t','` to set the field separator to the comma.
- `-k2` to indicate that `sort` has to work with the 2nd column.
- `-nr` to indicate that you want to sort numerically and in `r`everse (first the highest).

To get just the top 50, you can pipe to `head -50`, which will get the first 50 lines of the output of the previous command:

```
sort -t',' -k2 -nr file | head -50
```

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer is:

```bash
sort -t',' -k2 -nr file | head -50
```

This uses a ton of memory; gnu sort reads the file, then sorts it, then sends it to the output. It could do things differently if it had downstream context, like dropping lines that are no longer needs.

That's where [choose](https://github.com/jagprog5/choose/) comes in (I'm the author). Here's the equivalent command:

```bash
cat file | tail -n +2 | choose --out=50 --sort-reverse -n --field '^[^,]*+. \K.*+'
```

Explanation:

- `cat file`: read the file
- `tail -n +2`: remove the header line (accepted answer doesn't do this but it's needed for correctness)
- `--out=50`: limit the output to the first 50 lines
- `--sort-reverse -n`: sort in reverse numeric order
- `--field '^[^,]*+. \K.*+'`: match the number on each line.  the [expression](https://regex101.com/r/D67jYg) is tailored for the question's specific file format. Other examples include:

  - `^[^,]*+.\K[^,]*+` match the second field of a csv
  - `^(?>(?:[^,]*+.){N})\K[^,]*+` match the Nth field (replace N)

From now on, the header is ommited, but `tail` really should be used to get rid of the header line.

For the next benchmarks, let's generate a test file:

```bash
# generate 10 million lines, 114M size 
(for i in {1..10000000} ; do
    #       V deliberate space, following original question
    echo hi, $i
done) > file
cat file | shuf -o file
```

Measurements are done with the `time` command:

```bash
$ >choose_out.csv <file command time --verbose -- choose --sort-reverse -n --out=50 --field '^[^,]*+. \K.*+'
    Command being timed: "choose --sort-reverse -n --out=50 --field ^[^,]*+. \K.*+"
    User time (seconds): 12.06
    System time (seconds): 0.06
    Percent of CPU this job got: 99%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:12.13
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 4480
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 193
    Voluntary context switches: 1
    Involuntary context switches: 73
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 8
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

```bash
$ command time --verbose -- sort -t',' -k2 -nr file | head -50 >sort_out.csv
Command terminated by signal 13
    Command being timed: "sort -t, -k2 -nr file"
    User time (seconds): 48.07
    System time (seconds): 1.46
    Percent of CPU this job got: 332%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:14.90
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 675968
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 168596
    Voluntary context switches: 16
    Involuntary context switches: 3528
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

```bash
cmp -s choose_out.csv sort_out.csv && echo "same" || echo "different" # same
```

|  | choose | sort |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Elapsed (wall clock) time | 0:12.13 | 0:14.90 |
| User time | 12.06 | 48.07 |
| Maximum resident set size | 4480 | 675968 |

For this test case choose is faster in elapsed time, faster in CPU time, and uses way less memory.

The elapsed time comparison will vary based on hardware, but the general idea of using less CPU and less memory is constant.